# Управление мышью с помощью Python

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, мышь

Появилась необходимость ограничить управление мышью, а именно отключить возможность перемещения по вертикали или горизонтали. Python не знаю. Сам изучаю веб разработку, но скрипт написать хочется...

Вопрос: **есть ли встроенный API, или сторонние библиотеки, с помощью которых по-быстренькому можно было бы написать нечто подобное, или даже сложнее.**

Comment: попробуйте `pyautogui` https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй как то так:
`import pyautogui
x, y = pyautogui.position()#Ету строку можна вставить когда захотите опредилить на какой 
                                                             #висоте зафиксировать мишку
while True:

    pyautogui.moveTo(x, None)#Ето уже зафиксирует миш точнее он будет просто её переносить
                                                                         #в одну точку`